# Using singleton to create an array and declare it in TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to create a singleton NSMutableArray so I can use it on TableView as Titles. How to declare it in a TableView?

e.g.

```
cell.textLabel.text = ??? //Don't know how to declare it from the singleton.
```

Here is my singleton.m:

```
#import "Singleton.h"

@implementation Singleton
@synthesize Trees;


+(Singleton *) theTrees {

    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static Singleton *theTrees = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^ {
        theTrees = [[Singleton alloc] init];
        theTrees.Trees = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                  });
    return theTrees;
}

-(id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {

        // Variables
        [Trees addObject:@"Berzas"];
        [Trees addObject:@"Liepa"];
        [Trees addObject:@"Drebule"];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Please point me in the right direction, thank you.

Comment: I think you don't know exactly what you're doing or why.

Comment: At this point yeah, because I've tried a lot different methods that I found on stack overflow, please understand me, I'm just a beginner and I need help :)

Comment: I understand, but what you're asking doesn't make sense. You want to put some text in `cell.textLabel.text` from your singleton, but your singleton contains an array. Additionally your singleton is NOT really a singleton, because you can still use `init` to instantiate objects. Also, your `Trees` object is not initialized, so it will crash.

Comment: If you are new to iOS, I strongly recommend you follow some of Ray Wenderlich's tutorials (they will really help you understand iOS): http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no need to create a singleton class here. Just have a class or instance method somewhere

```
- (NSDictionary *)trees
```

and the implementation about the same as your method that returns a singleton, but just creating a singleton NSDictionary once.

Properties like "Trees" should be written in lowercase: "trees", not "Trees". 
Instance variables should start with an underscore, so

```
[_trees addObject:@"Berzas"];
```

That's done so that you always can distinguish between using accessor methods and accessing instance variables; they are not the same thing. Usually you would only access instance variables in your init method, and when implementing getters and setters for properties.